# Android intercept VoIP call durations

Tags: android, sip, voip

I need to intercept all VOIP calls made and received from my device, and
calculate total call duration.

Can you suggest reading material to research?

Thanks,
Bakai.

Comment: Any phone call that comes in?

Comment: yeap exactly. any call, from anynclient that comes in and out of phone.

Comment: Hi, were you able to do this? how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check every phone call that comes in you can extend a BroadcastReceiver and `@Override` the `onReceive` method. In your Manifest file you must register your broadcast receiver for the `PHONE_STATE` intent filter. This means your receiver will be triggered every time the `PHONE_STATE` changes.

In your `onReceive` method you can then get a `TelephonyManager` instance, and check for `CALL_STATE_RINGING` and other states to determine the time from ringing, to off hook, back to idle. That will give you a sense of the duration of the call.

Here's the documentation: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Here's an example of your manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.PhoneBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here's an example of the broadcast receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int callState = telephonyManager.getCallState();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }

    String incomingNumber = extras.getString("incoming_number");

    Log.d(TAG, "Receiving callStateChange: " + callState + " number: " + incomingNumber);

    switch (callState) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING :
            processIncomingNumber(context, incomingNumber);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE :
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.cancelAll();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks,
but code snippet you wrote is working only with normal GSM phone calls.

I need to work with VOIP/SIP calls.

The problem is that:

I can use onCallEstablished method from android.net.sip library.
But I need to intercept all SipManager objects on my phone.